How to properly abort Node readline promise question?
I'm not able to properly handle an user abortion of a promise readline question with SIGINT or Ctrl+D while rl.question waits for an user input:
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

const answer = await rl.question('>>> ');

The abortion results in:
Warning: Detected unsettled top-level await at file:///foo/bar/test.js:xx
const answer = await rl.question('>>> ');

I can mimic the intended behaviour with non promise readline like:
import * as readline from 'node:readline';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

let rej = () => {};
rl.on('close', () => {
  console.log('closing');
  rej();
});

const answer = await new Promise((r, j) => {
  rej = j;
  rl.question('>>> ', r);
}).catch(() => console.error('interrupted'));

How to safely handle such top level unsettled promises to be able to use the node:readline/promises interface?
Environment:
Node v22.2.0, ES module

Is there a reason you're not using try/catch around it, as you'd handle any other rejected promise when using async/await?

Wrapping it in try/catch block doesn't do any difference. try {
const answer = await rl.question('>>> ');
} catch {
console.error('interrupted');
}
At the first place I would like to learn how to handle this 'unsettled promise' warning better way.

Yikes. Even for an “experimental” module, it’s really bad that this isn’t accounted for in the implementation or even mentioned in the documentation.

"properly handle an user abortion of a promise readline question" - what exactly is the expected behavior? Did you want to get a rejection when the user sends SIGINT or Ctrl+D? Or did you want your program to end (just without a warning)? "How to safely handle such top level unsettled promises" - you can't handle them if they don't settle. But to get rid of the warning, you probably should wrap your application code in a async function main and not use top-level await, then just call that.

@Ry- Agreed. This is probably worth a bug report. Especially if the rl fires a close event, it shouldn't leave any promises pending.

I've been working on this to find an answer. and I guess it's a bug in nodejs

the only thing that i found is this : https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#exit-codes
exit code number 13

I've created the issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/53497
Let's see how it progresses.
